How to change the name or the key of a header while calling a post method on an aws wrapper api
Below are the headers I'm passing, while calling the AWS wrapper API:
halo_auth: B*******************************j
Tenant_ID: 6
Auth_Hash: 7078CE1DAFE607E1805AB0D9995C7440
Auth_Timestamp: 2024-04-05T11:13:46
Now I'm calling the main API via the wrapper API and I want to change the header named 'halo_auth' in the headers (see the headers above) to 'Authorization' while calling the main api and the rest of the key values in the headers should be passed to the main api as it is.
How can I achieve this using mapping template. Also, I want that if any additional headers are being sent while calling the wrapper api then they should also be sent while calling the main api as it is.
I tried to do this using the mapping template and by modifying the http headers, but was unable to do so

If the Auth_Hash is some actual credential, you should edit this out of your question and possibly change it on AWS, to secure your account.
